# get access to selected row data from outside table component

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a common component for the table which is being used in different pages through the app. Now the selection of rows is being saved inside the table component itself. I want to access the selected rows of data from its parent component whenever button pressed

Here is an example
https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-pond-3e5jp

Comment: "whenever button is pressed", what button are you referring to?

Comment: @rzwnahmd I have a button outside the table component, I have it on my example

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is pass maintain some state for selectedRows in you parent component then pass a callback to `Table` component that'll be called every time a row is selected or unselected. Here I have made some changes to your sandbox, hope it helps :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-sun-3nhue?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The problem with this approach is we are maintaining the selected row data at two places. One is with react-table itself and another one in our component

Comment: No we're not maintaining anything in our parent component, we are just accessing the data. We're not removing or adding rows in our parent state when there's a change in Table component, all that is done by the Table component. We're just getting the data and that's all

Comment: if you look at your example, there is `selectedRows` in state where you are storing all your selected state.

Comment: Yeah it's just stored there, it becomes a problem when we have to make changes to both Table component state and our parent component state when a row is selected/unselected. But we're not doing that, we're making changes just in the Table component and those changes are reflected in `selectedRows` automatically.

Comment: yeah but again the selected row data is being repeated twice one in react table and one in our parent component state

Comment: I would not consider that a problem, this is how you access data from the child components in React

Answer (score 1):

```
@jiltender 

    i fix my problem by doing this to get row data outside the table 
    
        rowProps={row =>(console.log(row)
                )} 
        

add this on parent components where u call the Table 
     <Table
            sortByProps={[]}
            columns={columns}
            rowProps={row =>(setSelectedItems(row))}  /// pass row props
           
          />
    
and the table side 
add this in 
function props 
` `rowProps = () => ({}) }) 

    function Table({ columns, data, showSpinnerProp, hiddenColumnsProps,getCellProps, getRowProps, height, sortByProps, source, 

    setSelectedItems,rowProps = () => ({}) }) {
        
        this will return u all the select data  you can call it before return 
        useEffect(() => {
            setSelectedItems = selectedFlatRows;
            rowProps(selectedFlatRows)
          }, [selectedFlatRows]);
        
        }
```

Comment: May you improve the formatting of your answer? It is somewhat unclear

Answer (score 0):

Create a state variable outside of the component, something like

```
const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);
```

And then pass this down to the component through the props. then on the button you can have some code like this

```
onPress = { () => props.setSelectedRows(selectedRows) }
```

Comment: The action button is lies outside the table component

Answer (score -1):

Connect the parent component with the Table with useEffects. A pseudo example below.

```
function TableComponent ({columns, data.., setSelectedRows}){

  const { ..., selectedFlatRows, state:{selectedRowIds} } = useTable({..})

  useEffect(() =>{
      setSelectedRows(selectedFlatRows)
  }, [selectedFlatRows])

  ......

}

function ParentComponent (props){
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows = useState ([])

  useEffect(() =>{
    // do your custom handle of the selection
  },[selectedTickers])

 return (
    ......
    <Table  
      columns={columns} 
      ....
      setSelectedRows={setSelectedTickers}>
    </Table>
    ......
 )

}
```

Comment: It will be a infinite loop causing error maximum update depth exceeded